# How to remove all childNodes from Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove all the childNodes from the javascript object. I referred W3Schools example. But they are using while loop and remove child node one by one. See the below code.

```
var list = document.getElementById("myList");

// As long as <ul> has a child node, remove it
while (list.hasChildNodes()) {   
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
}
```

[W3Schools Link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_removechild_while).

I have more than 1000 childNodes. So i want to remove it in single steps. Using while loop will get performance issue. Any one help on this.

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: do `$(list).html("")` and all thing inside it get removed.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove `innerHtml` of the element to get rid of all the childnodes

```
document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML = ""
```

Comment: Hi Bharathi,check like this $(this.gXaxisEle).empty();